# How to change Tab Control Background Color (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

how can I change the grey part into white color?
I want my tabcontrol filled with full white color.

[image]

So far what i did is like this:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim tp As TabPage = TabControl1.TabPages(e.Index)
    Dim br As Brush
    Dim sf As New StringFormat

    Dim r As New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 2, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 2)

    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    Dim strTitle As String = tp.Text

    'If the current index is the Selected Index, change the color 
    If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = e.Index Then

        'this is the background color of the tabpage header
        br = New SolidBrush(Color.White) ' chnge to your choice
        g.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)

        'this is the foreground color of the text in the tab header
        br = New SolidBrush(Color.Black) ' change to your choice
        g.DrawString(strTitle, TabControl1.Font, br, r, sf)

    Else

        'these are the colors for the unselected tab pages 
        br = New SolidBrush(Color.White) ' Change this to your preference
        g.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds)
        br = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        g.DrawString(strTitle, TabControl1.Font, br, r, sf)

    End If
End Sub
```

and I also put this at PageLoad function:

```
TabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
For Each tg As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
    tg.BackColor = Color.White
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property to do this. However it is possible by using something like this

http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm

All controls on this site are freely available under MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

Spending fair time to research if someone find a solution; There could be some work around. But according to [MSDN Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4sc610z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

TabControl.BackColor Property

> NET Framework (current version)      **This API supports the product
>   infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.**
>
> This member is not meaningful for this control.
>
> Namespace:   System.Windows.Forms Assembly:  System.Windows.Forms (in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll)

As far as I understand, this is adjustable from user's windows setting. (`Highlight Color`) of `TabControl`, Forms and other controls; otherwise MS could simply turn this property on.

Answer (score 0):

I make a trick to get around this, I put on the gray part a white label and I have the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since that color segment of the tabcontrol is unpaintable and cannot be controlled, you have to use a panel or label, etc. to cover up the background color where there is no tabpage header.  I use a panel to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This statement working correctly:

```
Dim PutBackColor As Boolean = False
    Private Sub TabControl1_DrawItem(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.DrawItem
        If Me.PutBackColor = False Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(<YourColor>), 0 , 0, e.Bounds.Width + 2, e.Bounds.Height + 2)
            Me.PutBackColor = True
        End If
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(<YourColor>), 0 , 0, e.Bounds.Width + 2, e.Bounds.Height + 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.TabControl1.TabPages(e.In  dex).Text, e.Font, Brushes.White, e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Y + 5)
        If e.State = DrawItemState.Selected Then
            Me.PutBackColor = False
        End If
 End Sub
```